# Application 32 Bit - Outlook 64bit - Windows 10 64 Bit Mapi32.dll

Tags: outlook

We have an application which is only 32bit. We have some customers which are using Microsoft Outlook 64 Bit (365, 2016, 2019 Version). Operating System is Windows 10 64 Bit. The thing is that you can add the attachement in our software automatically to outlook. It opens outlook window automatically with the attachement you can just have to write the text.

I could solve some problems by adding some registry keys for the outlook 32bit edition.
It is programmed in delphi and the function is mapisendmail

Normally it shows an error that the standard e-mail client is not configured.

now for 64bit there is no solution for windows 64bit with outlook64 bit. I have tried several things like outlook64bridge etc. but nothing works.

Is it possible to solve this problem on user side?

Thanks